# Titles of Wordpress posts aren't always clickable to the full post/permalink page

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

my Wordpress blog is set up so that there is a title, snippet, and "Read More" link. The title is supposed to be clickable to the full post. However, if the title is only one line long, it is not clickable. If it breaks onto 2 or more lines, it becomes clickable. Oddly enough I also notice that when the title is on 2 lines, only the top line is clickable.

This used to work properly and I'm wondering if something changed with a recent update. Also, I am using the Type Kit font replacement plugin, but as I said, it used to work before so I don't think that's the problem. Anyone have a suggestion for getting my titles to be clickable again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to post a link in order for this to be diagnosed correctly, but the problem almost certainly is that an invisible element is sitting on top of your title.